# Sharing screen WITHOUT audio? [amazon-chime-sdk]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I've been wondering how can I stop the audio stream even if the user checks the audio checkbox in the sharescreen Chrome pop-up. Is there any setting, any flag that I can tick as false that won't share the audio?
[The sharescreen popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cTyH.png)

I was jumping between *chime-sdk*, and *chime-sdk-react-components* documentations and wasn't able to find the thing I am looking for.
This is the function I'm currently using and I suppose that if there is any way of stopping the audio stream I would put it right here.

```
const createSession = async () => {
    try {
      const contentShareStream = await meetingSession.audioVideo!.startContentShareFromScreenCapture();
      meetingSession.audioVideo!.addContentShareObserver(observer);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Nice question, I needed to know this as well